# call js methods from python

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, execjs

I'm building an add-on for Kodi in python. For this, I need to call some js methods from python. I've a js sdk. how do I call it's methods from python. I'm using execjs. If I write simple js methods, there is no issue, but using execjs, SDK's methods are not accessible. Need help.

Comment: Do you just want to run some JS code (and what it does is none of your concern), or do you want to run JS to bring back some value into python land? For the latter, it really matters what you are trying to execute in JS. Like what it usually returns.

Comment: I want the returns too.

Comment: The js library is written in UnderscoreJS. How do I call it's method from python?